# Equal elements' height in rows using w3.css

Tags: html, css, alignment, w3c, w3.css

I've been trying to make my rows' elements' height be equal but still haven't succeeded.
Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Thanks, cheers.

```
<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter w3-green text-center matrix-element">
            <h3><i class="material-icons">person</i> name</h3>
            <p>100112</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter w3-green text-center matrix-element">
        <h3><i class="material-icons">person</i> name</h3>
        <p>100112</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter w3-green text-center matrix-element">
        <h3><i class="material-icons">person</i> name</h3>
        <p>100112</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter w3-green text-center matrix-element">
            <h3><i class="material-icons w3-xxlarge">remove_circle_outline</i></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Berger92/0s154y8h/)

Comment: Your row heights all look the same to me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flexbox` can do that

```
.w3-row {
    display: flex;
}

.w3-container {
    flex:1;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0s154y8h/8/)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to remove the CSS class `w3-xxlarge` from the `<i>`-tag containing the circular glyph, because the line-height of that glyph using that class differs from the default line-height for the glyps or text in the other divs.

I have also added `min-height: 20px;` for the `p`-tags to compensate for no content.

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awx6zfea/)**

Comment: Thanks, but need larger icon.

Comment: Agreed, Paulie_D's solution is able to cope with the larger icon without any help, so that solution is superior.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem recently, and flexbox styling can work unless you need your site to be suitable for a wider range of browsers eg. IE9 and below ref:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

I use a negative margin technique which would mean doing this:

```
.w3-quarter {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;   
}
```

Works on bootstrap grid rows as well!

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0s154y8h/10/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check this up.