# Responsive html layout height 100% is not according to parent div

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I'm really new in html

This is my code

```
<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-container w3-half w3-padding-64 w3-orange w3-text-white w3-center" style="height:100%">
        <p style="font-size:calc(11px + 1vw);"> OUR <b>VISION</b></br></br>
        To become the best foundation that is able to nurture holistic global leaders</p>
    </div>


    <div class="w3-container w3-half w3-padding-64 w3-orange w3-text-white w3-center" style="height:100%">
        <p style="font-size:calc(11px + 1vw);"> OUR <b>MISSION</b></br></br>
        Developing young muslim leaders by nurturing entrepreneurial mindset in order to provide the best
        solution for mankind through Islamic values</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have 2 column in a row. This is what happened

[my first column leaves empty white space below it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkLfd.png)

Is there any way to have both my columns to extend to 100% parent div's height?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921089/equal-elements-height-in-rows-using-w3-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex

```css
.w3-row{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.w3-container {
flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-container w3-half w3-padding-64 w3-orange w3-text-white w3-center" style="height:100%">
        <p style="font-size:calc(11px + 1vw);"> OUR <b>VISION</b></br></br>
        To become the best foundation that is able to nurture holistic global leaders</p>
    </div>


    <div class="w3-container w3-half w3-padding-64 w3-orange w3-text-white w3-center" style="height:100%">
        <p style="font-size:calc(11px + 1vw);"> OUR <b>MISSION</b></br></br>
        Developing young muslim leaders by nurturing entrepreneurial mindset in order to provide the best
        solution for mankind through Islamic values</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use flex like @Supraja suggested, but an even simpler solution is to give the orange bg to the container of the columns instead of the column itself.

so put `.w3-orange` on the div with `w3-row` class:

```
<div class="w3-row w3-orange">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the problem of responsive layouts.

Add the orange background-color to the w3-row.

To prevent the different hights you have to add some hight values to your .w3-containers.